# update existing row in mysql using php coding

Tags: php, mysql, button, save

in my db i have 20+ columns. i added 19 columns throught input form and stored in db succesfully. i fetch few rows from db in my main page. in my main page 1 more column is there. that is status column, it is a combo box type. if i click status column it should show 4 values. i want to select one of the values and then when i click save button it must go to stored in db with that same ID. how to do that? i tried but its not updated in mysql db...

mainpage combo box coding:

```
echo "\t<td><form action=statusdb.php method=post>
<select name=update><option value=empty></option><option value=Confirm>Confirm</option><option value=Processing>Processing</option><option value=Pending>Pending</option><option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option></select>
<input name=\"update[".$a_row['slno']."]\"; type=submit id=id value=Save></form>
</td>\n";
```

status db coding:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{ 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE guestdetails SET status = '" . $_POST['update'] ."'");
if(!$sql)
{
    die("Error" .mysql_error());
}
}
```

help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IF should be $_POST, not $_GET
Also, need to add WHERE clause, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{ 
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
  $update= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update']);

  $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE guestdetails SET status = '$update' WHERE id='$id'");
if(!$sql)
{
    die("Error" .mysql_error());
}
}
```

Also, you used name `update` twice, once in `<select>` once in `<input>`, take that one from `<input>` out, make it hidden field with name `id` and value of your `slno` row:

```
echo "\t<td>
  <form action=statusdb.php method=post>
    <select name=update>
      <option value=empty></option>
      <option value=Confirm>Confirm</option>
      <option value=Processing>Processing</option>
      <option value=Pending>Pending</option>
      <option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option>
    </select>
    <input name='id' type='hidden' value='".$a_row['slno']."';>
    <input type='submit'>Save</button>
  </form>
</td>\n";
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i got it. first i used where clause but here i forget to update. i just collapsing the name, value ids... now OK

Comment: can't understand.. what r u telling to me?

Comment: You can accept answer that help you with the question. Also, you can vote up answer.

Comment: i did that. but vote up requires 15 reputation. what to do? i am a newbie. how to get reputation?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
<form action="statusdb.php" method="post">
<?php
while($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $sl_no = $a_row['slno'];
    echo '<select name="update['.$sl_no.']"><option value=empty></option><option value=Confirm>Confirm</option><option value=Processing>Processing</option><option value=Pending>Pending</option><option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option></select> '; 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="sl_no[]" value="'.$sl_no.'" />'; 
} 
?>
<input name="update_rows" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update_rows'])) {
    $nums = $_POST['sl_no'];
    $update = $_POST['update'];
    foreach($nums as $sl) {
        $sl_no = $sl;
        $val = $update[$sl_no];
        $sql_update = mysql_query("UPDATE guestdetails SET status = '$val' WHERE sl_no='$sl_no'");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are not submitting any `id` to `status db`.

Comment: i am submitting the if(isset($_GET['id'])) & in my form tag submit button code i mentioned it id=id.. am i right or wrong?

Comment: but your `html` form does not have an element with a name `id` so when you submit the form `isset($_GET['id'])` will always generate a `false` bool and the script won't execute further. Another thing is your form has a `method = 'post'` but you are sending a `get` request. Moreover your `sql` query will update all the row's `status`. you need to have some thing like this `UPDATE guestdetails SET status = <your status> WHERE id = <your id>` here you are basically selecting a single row by specifying a `id`(`id` has to be a valid row name).

Comment: try this `echo "\t<td><form action=statusdb.php method=post>
<select name=update><option value=empty></option><option value=Confirm>Confirm</option><option value=Processing>Processing</option><option value=Pending>Pending</option><option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option></select>
<input name='id' type=submit value =".$a_row['slno']."></form>
</td>\n";`