# Change Row in MySQL using PHP Code

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently getting the error "Fatal Error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in Update.php on line 14. I need to know how I can fix this.

Here's Update.php:

```
 <?php
    $post_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $post = json_decode($post_json, true);  
    $response = array();
$configs = include('config.php');
  $mysqli = new mysqli($configs["host"], $configs["username"], $configs["password"], "Account");  if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    die("Error connecting to MySQL database (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error);
  }
    $name = $post["Name"];
    $rank = $post["Rank"];
    $perm = (int) $post["Perm"];    

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET `rank`=?,`rankPerm`=? WHERE `name`=?");
  $stmt->bind_param("sis", $rank, (int) $perm, $name);
  $stmt->execute();
?>
```

I believe that the error is in the (int) part of line 14, but I don't know what's wrong.

I'm trying to edit the "rank" part of one of these rows with this PHP file when executed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F47EU.jpg

Thanks for all of your help in advance!

NOTE: Already checked [update existing row in mysql using php coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195254/update-existing-row-in-mysql-using-php-coding)

Comment: why two times `(int)` . Also can you show output of `var_dump($post);`?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> May be this is the problem...

```
$name = $_post["Name"];
$rank = $_post["Rank"];
$perm = (int) $_post["Perm"];
```

Comment: `$_post`? he set `$post`, why he must use `$_post` ?

Comment: This worked, but I have to restart my gameserver for the changes to take effect... weird.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<?php
        $post_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $post = json_decode($post_json, true);  
        $response = array();
        $configs = include('config.php');
        $mysqli = new mysqli($configs["host"], $configs["username"], $configs["password"], "Account");  if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        die("Error connecting to MySQL database (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error);
      }
        $name = $post["Name"];
        $rank = $post["Rank"];
        $perm = (int) $post["Perm"];
        $sis="sis";

      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET `rank`=?,`rankPerm`=? WHERE `name`=?");
      $stmt->bind_param($sis, $rank, $perm, $name);
      $stmt->execute();
    ?>
```

I believe you have to pass variables rather than a string.

Or you could use bindvalue() instead of bindparam() if you're using PDO.

Comment: And why to use this? any explanation?

Comment: `I believe you have to pass variables rather than a string`.  no it's not:- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

From Php.net

> Note:
>   Care must be taken when using mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in conjunction with call_user_func_array(). Note that mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be passed by reference, whereas call_user_func_array() can accept as a parameter a list of variables that can represent references or values.

It seems when you add a type conversion as a parameter to a function Php doesn't keep the reference, if you remove the (int) in the function call should be fine.

`$stmt->bind_param("sis", $rank, (int) $perm, $name);`

To

`$stmt->bind_param("sis", $rank, $perm, $name);`

Comment: Unfortunately, this generated a nullPointerException.